# Clicking in a TextField causes the soft keyboard to cover the entire android emulator screen

Tags: flutter, android-softkeyboard

I am using Android Studio. I have created my app in flutter. I have a Windows 10 machine.

When I run the app on the Android emulator and click in a TextField widget the soft keyboard comes up. Sometimes it is fine but other times there is a white, blank portion above the keyboard that covers everything above the keyboard. If I hide the keyboard the TextField is there. I can type and enter text into the TextField but I can  not see what I am typing.

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are the widgets of the screen scrollable? if not, then wrap them in a `SingleChildScrollView`, this might help.

Answer (score 0):

There are atleast 2 ways to fix this:

1. Wrap your parent container of the `TextField` in a `SingleChildScrollView` so that it will allow to scroll when the keboard comes up.
2. Use the package [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility). From the package listen to the event `KeyboardVisibility.onChange` and then you can change the height and top padding of your container, so the textfield will not get behind the keyboard

Comment: Thank you. I will try the flutter_keyboard_visibility package. The TextField is already wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView.